# Getting this error "await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules" in chrome extension with async await

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I can't understand why this is throwing that error when I am working inside async await functions... Not sure if makes a difference but I am executing this code inside the content script of a chrome extension

Thanks in advance!

```
const getFromStorage = async function(key) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    chrome.storage.sync.get(key, resolve);
})
    .then(result => {
        if (key == null) return result;
        else return result[key];
    });
}

let updateArray = await getFromStorage("toSaveArray");
```

Comment: As the error says, you can't use `await` except A) Inside an `async` function, or B) In the top level of an ESM module. The top level of an extension content script is neither of those things, so you can't use `await` there.

Comment: Yes that seems right, thank you

Comment: Is there a way to make a content script an ESM module?

Answer (score 0):

Top level await is not yet supported

You probably have to use an an Anonymous Function, for example:

```js
(async () => {
  let updateArray = await getFromStorage("toSaveArray");
})();
```