# await Error at Top Level Module in Chrome Extension Service_worker

Tags: google-chrome-extension, async-await

I have a sequence of code that is at the top level of my script:

```
await tmrs=chrome.storage.local.get("tmrs");
console.log(tmrs);
await data=chrome.storage.local.get("Auto_Select_051969");
console.log(data);
if (data==null) {
   store_data();
   await data=chrome.storage.local.get("Auto_Select_051969");
}
```

However I get the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules
```

This is in a service_worker script. Is there some kind of restriction? How do I fix this? TIA.

I found this: [Getting this error "await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules" in chrome extension with async await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72657382/getting-this-error-await-is-only-valid-in-async-functions-and-the-top-level-bod) but I'm not sure this applies or if the anonymous function is really the solution.

**Updated Code:**

```
(async () => {
   let tmrs=await chrome.storage.local.get("tmrs");
})();
console.log(tmrs);
```

Comment: given link seems to be the one of the right approaches and should work. did you face any issue with this implementing it?

Comment: Haven't tried yet as I was not sure it was applicable. I'll try now. Thanks.

Comment: The `await` keyword should come immediately after the equals sign, e.g. `tmrs=await chrome.storage.local.get("tmrs");`

Comment: Chrome forbids top-level await in a service worker [intentionally](https://crrev.com/832849). It can't be circumvented, so you'll have to use an async function.

Comment: Your updated code is incorrect: you must use the variable inside the function, not outside.

Comment: That's a problem as I need that value in multiple places further down the code. There is no way to get it outside? That makes it worthless. I have to use that function every time I want to use that variable?

Comment: `data` will never be `null`, because `chrome.storage.local.get()` returns an object. If the key passed to this function doesn't exist, then the function returns an empty object: `{}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap ***all*** of your service worker code in an async IIFE, including the definition of store_data().

```
(async () => {
    function store_data() {
        console.log("storing data");
    }
    
    tmrs = await chrome.storage.local.get("tmrs");
    console.log(tmrs);
    data = await chrome.storage.local.get("Auto_Select_051969");
    console.log(data);
    if (data == null) {
        store_data();
        data = await chrome.storage.local.get("Auto_Select_051969");
    }
})();
```

Explanation:

https://usefulangle.com/post/248/javascript-async-anonymous-function-iife

> Immediately-invoked Function Expression (IIFE), is a technique to
> execute a Javascript function as soon as they are created. It is good
> way of declaring variables and executing code without polluting the
> global namespace. These are also called anonymous functions as they
> have no defined names.
>
> Very often it is required to use the await operator immediately (for
> example page load). The await can however be used only inside an async
> function. But instead of defining a new async function and calling it,
> it is better to use the IIFE pattern to create an async function that
> will be immediately called.